# Eclipse and package-specific editor preferences

Tags: eclipse, formatting

I'm currently working on several different projects - some are for courses, while others are personal. For my personal projects, I prefer using Eclipse's default editor settings with slight modification. This includes the default setting of tabs being equivalent to 4 spaces, which I find aesthetically preferable.

However, I have a couple programming projects this semester for one course in which the instructor lists one formatting requirement as 2-3 spaces for tabs. While I could bite the bullet and adjust everything down to 3 spaces, I'm wondering if there's a way around that.

Is there any way to adjust Editor Preferences in Eclipse local to a package/project, while maintaining a different set of global preferences?

Comment: It's a tangent to your question, but this situation is exactly why using spaces for indentation is bad idea. A "unit of indentation" should be consistent (represented by a single tab character), so that each person can choose to display them as he prefers (render the tab as 1 space, 4 spaces, 37 spaces, whatever). Forcing the use of space characters to indicate indentation is a really dirty band-aid that our industry has accepted for far too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general editor preferences are global to the workspace.

Some editors such as the Java editor support some options on a per-project basis but this doesn't include tab settings and the like.

I would suggest using separate workspaces for your personal projects and your course projects. You can then have different settings in each workspace. This may also help manage your projects.

You can also set up multiple profiles in the Code Formatter settings in the preferences. You could use these to format projects differently.

Comment: Thanks! I set up a profile under the Code Formatter settings to  use before exporting my source code for assignments.